# CASE WHEN THEN Least value from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. I need least value of 2nd table within 1st table. I want to fill the column `least_t2` where value will come from `table2` least value.

```
table1
id   name  d1   d2   d3
1    asd   1    2    3
```

```
table2
id   name  c1   c2   c3   c4
1    poi   7    5    6    9
```

My output table wil be like below from `table1`

```
id   name  d1   d2   d3   least  least_t2
1    asd   1    2    3    1        b
```

My query is as:

```
select * , least(d1, d2, d3),
    (CASE least(d1, d2, d3)
        WHEN d1  THEN  (CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4) from `table2`
                                WHEN c1  THEN 'a'
                                WHEN c2  THEN 'b'
                                WHEN c3  THEN 'c'
                                WHEN c4  THEN 'd'
                        END)
        WHEN d2  THEN  (CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4) from `table2`
                                WHEN c1  THEN 'a'
                                WHEN c2  THEN 'b'
                                WHEN c3  THEN 'c'
                                WHEN c4  THEN 'd'
                        END)
        WHEN d3  THEN   (CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4) from `table2`
                                WHEN c1  THEN 'a'
                                WHEN c2  THEN 'b'
                                WHEN c3  THEN 'c'
                                WHEN c4  THEN 'd'
                        END)

END) as least_t2
FROM `table1`
```

With the above query no result is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    LEAST(t1.d1, t1.d2, t1.d3) AS `least`,
    CASE WHEN t2.c1 = LEAST(t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t2.cr) THEN 'a'
         WHEN t2.c2 = LEAST(t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t2.cr) THEN 'b'
         WHEN t2.c3 = LEAST(t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t2.cr) THEN 'c'
         WHEN t2.c4 = LEAST(t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t2.cr) THEN 'd'
         ELSE 'Unknown' END AS least_t2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If `table1` and `table2` can be joined using the column `id`  , the following query will do.

```
select t1.*,
       least(d1, d2, d3) as least,
       case least(c1, c2, c3, c4) 
            when c1 then 'a'
            when c2 then 'b'
            when c3 then 'c'
            when c1 then 'd'
       end as  least_t2 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code may this works.

```
select * , least(d1, d2, d3),
    (CASE least(d1, d2, d3)
        WHEN d1  THEN  (select CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4) 
                                WHEN c1  THEN 'a'
                                WHEN c2  THEN 'b'
                                WHEN c3  THEN 'c'
                                WHEN c4  THEN 'd'
                        END from `table2` )
        WHEN d2  THEN  (select CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4) 
                                WHEN c1  THEN 'a'
                                WHEN c2  THEN 'b'
                                WHEN c3  THEN 'c'
                                WHEN c4  THEN 'd'
                        END from `table2` )
        WHEN d3  THEN   (select CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4) 
                                WHEN c1  THEN 'a'
                                WHEN c2  THEN 'b'
                                WHEN c3  THEN 'c'
                                WHEN c4  THEN 'd'
                        END from `table2` )

END) as least_t2
FROM `table1`
```

or

```
select * , least(d1, d2, d3),(select CASE least(c1, c2, c3, c4)  WHEN c1  THEN 'a' WHEN c2  THEN 'b' WHEN c3  THEN 'c' WHEN c4  THEN 'd' END from `table2`) as least_t2
FROM `table1`
```